# Sort array object work only in Firefox ? - bug in Chrome and Safari?

Tags: javascript, performance, sorting, debugging, browser

Hello guys i have a code with `Google Maps Api V3` where there are a lot of markers and each marker is push in this array object `markers = []`

In each marker i have a particular property, that is `zIndex` (i thinks is a part of **API** google) and value, in my case, is `Time Stamp`.

I want to sort the array object by `zIndex` from the biggest to the smallest in this way:

```
markers.sort(function(a, b) {
 return (a.getZIndex()) < (b.getZIndex());
});
```

This sorting, for my code, works **ONLY** in Firefox while in Safari and Chrome is not correct.
To have a correct sort event in other browser i had to change sorting in this:

```
markers.sort(function(a, b) {
 return (b.getZIndex()) - (a.getZIndex());
});
```

How is possible ???
I have created a similiar code in **jsfiddle** https://jsfiddle.net/4mqoavom/17/ 
but works in each browser.

Unfortunately my code is too big to paste here but i'm sure there aren't problem in other places. 
The sorting is immediately after the creation of array object (with all markers inside).

Has this ever happened to you?
Maybe is problem of my code, about Chrome and Safari browsers or about sort of `getZIndex()` ?

In my case it almost seems like the problem in sorting is the operator `<`

I hope can you say me something....thanks a lot !

Comment: a comparison result misses the needed range, because it returns only zero (false) and one (true), but never `-1` or any number smaller than one, which necessary for sorting an unsorted array.

Comment: **Please read the doc:** *https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort*